# Select all element within specific class if its not found in a selector

Tags: css

I want to set a width of span element within 'select2-container' class if its outside any table

I try with this code but it doesn't work it will select all span elements even if it's inside a table.

```
body *:not(table) .select2-container {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

I also try with `body *:not(td) .select2-container {...` but it also not worked.

Answer (score 0):

you need to redifine class one more time,

```
.select2-container {
    width: 100% !important;
}

table .select2-container {
    width: unset;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work the select2 make to element a fixed width at creating span.
so at making  width unset will ignore the constant width.